# Jailbreak an officially unlocked iPhone

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, unlock

My iPhone 3GS was unlocked using O2's [official](http://service.o2.co.uk/IQ/SRVS/CGI-BIN/WEBCGI.EXE/,/?New,Kb=Companion,question=ref%28User%29%3astr%28Mobile%29,CASE=17424) [method](https://www.o2.co.uk/apps/help/help?qid=1&q1=2&route=unlocking&case=Handset%20Unlocking%20Form).

I am considering jailbreaking but am unsure if this will affect the unlock status of the handset.

The jailbreak options available seem a little bewildering, so is there a specific jailbreak method which doesn't unlock and will leave my iPhone with the official unlock?

What I really don't want to happen is to jailbreak and have the phone lock again on the next iOS update.

I am currently running iOS 4.3.3 and use iTunes on Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't affect the unlock.  A legitimate (ie sanctioned by the carrier and not hardware/software) unlock happens at the carrier level and jailbreaking doesn't affect that.

Comment: Is there a specific tool I need to use? I've been on the googles and found this quote: "NOTE: Those of you who rely on a carrier unlock MUST STAY AWAY from Redsn0w and stock iOS 4.3.3 firmware." (http://www.redmondpie.com/jailbreak-4.3.3-ios-iphone-4-3gs-ipad-ipod-touch-4g-3g-using-redsn0w-how-to-tutorial/)

Comment: @Shevek that means people who are locked to a carrier and use jailbreak to *unlock their carrier lock*. In your case, you're not locked to a carrier. But I don't think the *official carrier unlock* is **only** at carrier level, though I agree jailbreak certainly will **not** affect your unlock.

Comment: so I can safely use either Redsn0w or Sn0wbreeze then?

Comment: ah, the IMPORTANT FOR UNLOCKERS section on this page explains it quite well: http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=14563&laid=

Answer (score 1):

Follow this wizard: http://www.iclarified.com/jailbreak/iphone3gs/firmware.php

Comment: doesn't include 4.3.3 yet

Comment: although if I select 4.3.2 it ends up at a Redsn0w page about 4.3.3!

Comment: Do you object to jailbreaking on 4.3.3 instead of 4.3.2?